# Generating external references to the intrinsics used in instruction patterns in machine description

Tags: gcc, intrinsics

I would like to have the created output assembly listing include explicit external references to the symbols used in instruction patterns definitions. For example, for the TIC6X platform whenever "divsi3_insn" is expanded to the "call __c6xabi_divi" instruction, then it should be accompanied by ".global __c6xabi_divi" pseudo-op. My understanding is that I could accomplish this with something alike:

```
" .global __c6xabi_divi\; call __c6xabi_divi"
```

However, this will only work if somewhere along the road no attempt will be made to parallelize execution with the preceding instruction, e.g.

```
  stw .d2t2   B3, *+B15(32)
|| .global __c6xabi_divi    ;; this will fail the assembler
  call __c6xabi_divi
```

I haven't noticed any occurences of parallelization of the preceding instruction with the subsequent template expansion but this doesn't prove that it would work 100% cases.

Anyway, I am too fresh to gcc internals to judge by myself if the above would be a preferred way to go. Would anyone comment on this? Or maybe there's a better way to achieve the described effect?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have come up with the following. The simple output template in the instruction pattern, such as

```
"%|%.\\tcall\\t%$\\t__c6xabi_divi"
```

has to be replaced with the following code (ofc it can be extracted to a separate function):

```
{
  tree    id = build_libfunc_function("_c6xabi_divi");
  mark_referenced(DECL_ASSEMBLER_NAME (id));
  assemble_external(id);

  return "%|%.\\tcall\\t%$\\t__c6xabi_divi";
}
```